# Реализация IClonable для двусвязного списка

Tags: c#, интерфейс, двусвязный-список

Есть класс двусвязного списка, выглядит так:

```
class DoublyNode<T>
{
    public DoublyNode(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public DoublyNode<T> Previous { get; set; }
    public DoublyNode<T> Next { get; set; }
}

public class DoublyLinkedList<T>:IDeque<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICloneable
{
    DoublyNode<T> head; // головной/первый элемент
    DoublyNode<T> tail; // последний/хвостовой элемент
    int count;  // количество элементов в списке
    
    //различные методы

        public object DeepClone()
    {
        DoublyNode<T> clonedHead = new DoublyNode<T>(head.Data)
        {
            Data = head.Data,
            Previous = head.Previous,
            Next = head.Next
        };
        DoublyNode<T> clonedTail = new DoublyNode<T>(tail.Data)
        {
            Data = tail.Data,
            Previous = head.Previous,    //вот в этих местах нужен какой-то цикл для обхода всех нодов
            Next = tail.Next
        };
        int clonedCount = Count();
        return new DoublyLinkedList<T>
        {
            head = clonedHead,
            tail = clonedTail,         //и здесь
            count = clonedCount
        };
    }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return DeepClone();
    }
}
```

Необходимо реализовать метод Clone() интерфейса ICloneable. Я написал его в методе DeepClone, но работает он не совсем правильно, так как у каждого нода DoublyNode есть информация о предыдущем и следующем ноде, которая хранится в точно таком же ноде, у которого точно также есть информация и так далее до конца списка можно уходить вглубь.

Как я понял, здесь нужно циклом как то рекурсивно с проверкой на null обойти все ноды.

Если нужен весь код класса, я отредактирую.

Comment: В C# есть уже готовый класс двусвязного списка `LinkedList<T>`, не хотите посмотреть его исходники и то, как там реализован ICloneable?

Comment: В описании интерфейса [ICloneable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-5.0) см. Notes to Implementers. Его не рекомендуется реализовывать. Потому что нет общепринятого стандарта: должен ли он возвращать глубокую (deep) или поверхностную (shallow) копию объекта. Лучше просто сделайте метод клонирования (без интерфейса!), который вместо `object` возвращает реальный тип: `DoublyLinkedList<T> Clone()`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov допустим я опущу интерфейс, однако проблема остается: нужен какой-то цикл, который будет перебирать все ноды исходного списка и создавать новые, вот как это сделать я и не понимаю

Comment: @AK у готового класса, как я вижу есть только неполное копирование и то без интерфейса

Comment: 1) Как вам уже сказал АК, используйте LinkedList 2) Вы не можете реализовать операцию DeepClone, так как ее в общем случае не поддерживает generic-тип Т 3) Если вы все таки ограничите T хотя бы legacy ICloneable (или своим IDeepCloneable), то просто реализуйте аналогичный интерфейс и для DoublyNode, а дальше рекурсивные вызовы сделают все за вас

Answer (score 2):

```
public object Clone()
    {
        DoublyLinkedList<T> clone = new DoublyLinkedList<T>();
        foreach(T element in this)
        {
            clone.AddLast((T)element.Clone());
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

Где AddLast():

```
 public void AddLast(T data)
    {
        DoublyNode<T> node = new DoublyNode<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
            head = node;
        else
        {
            tail.Next = node;
            node.Previous = tail;
        }
        tail = node;
        count++;
    }
```

Также перед этим нужно ограничить T чтобы он наследовал IClonable

Comment: Если тип T ссылочный, то никакого клонирования не произойдет, произойдет клонирование ссылок на эти объекты.